# When importing Jackson-Core-1.x.x and Jackson-Mapper-1.x.x I receive a duplicate files during packaging of APK error

Tags: android-studio, jackson, duplicates

I have a project that is dependent on having both `Jackson-Core` and `Jackson-Mapper` from the old Codehaus 1.x.x maven repositories.

However when importing the two as libraries I receive an `duplicate files during packaging of APK` error.

Is there any way to get around this?

Full error:

```
Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\Tukajo\AndroidStudioProjects\buruburu\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
Path in archive: META-INF/ASL2.0
Origin 1: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\buruburu\lib\libs\jackson-mapper-asl2-1.9.13.jar
Origin 2: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\buruburu\lib\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
```

And if I add:

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

to the build.gradle file...

I get a new error:

```
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
File 1: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\buruburu\lib\libs\jackson-mapper-asl2-1.9.13.jar
File 2: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\buruburu\lib\libs\jackson-mapper-asl2-1.9.13.jar
```

Comment: One year, and no answer? I got the same problem just now.

Answer (score 0):

Instructing like below in gradle resolved this issue for me. Is this right way to do or recommended? Not sure.

```
android {

    //Other scripts

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "**"
    }

}
```